# Add user to model before saving with DjangoModelFormMutation

Tags: django-forms, graphene-django

I have a Django `Log` model which has many-to-one with a `User`

```py
from django.db import models

class Log(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I have a Django form for the `Log`

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm

class LogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        exclude = ("user",)
```

I have a graphene-django mutation to enable `Log` creation

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django.forms.mutation import DjangoModelFormMutation

class LogType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = "__all__"

class CreateLogMutation(DjangoModelFormMutation):
    log = graphene.Field(LogType)

    class Meta:
        form_class = LogForm
```

How do I set `Log.user` to the current user before saving? With Django class-based views you would do as follows:

```py
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class LogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Log
    form_class = LogForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

How is this achieved with graphene-django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `perform_mutate` and add the user there. `pefrom_mutate` is called after Django's `Form.is_valid`.

```py
class CreateLogMutation(DjangoModelFormMutation):
    log = graphene.Field(LogType)

    class Meta:
        form_class = LogForm

    @classmethod
    def perform_mutate(cls, form, info):
        form.instance.user = info.context.user
        return super().perform_mutate(form, info)
```